# combine calculated field to angularfire2 list

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

i try to combine new created field to angularfire2 list, but got lost to implement maping,

```
 const listLoc = this.afdb.list('/userLocations');
listLoc.snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(actions => {
    actions.forEach(action => {
      let data = action.payload.val();
      let placeLocation = {
        lat: data.lat,
        lng: data.lng
      }
      let usersLocation = {
        lat: -24.25747,
        lng: 112.752
      };
      let distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
        usersLocation,
        placeLocation,
        'km'
      ).toFixed(2);
      console.log('action payload.val()', data, distance);
    });
  });
```

i am expecting something like data.distance as result so i can call data and distance will include.

i am trying to figure out how to implement this inside angularfire2 list

```
data.map( location ){
 location.distance =  bla bla bla // distance method will be here
}
```

Please Guide, thank you.

Comment: This is very confusing, what are you trying to do and what doesn't work?

Comment: i want to include distance inside data array ,but need guidance to use mapping in correct way, so i can call it from view like this one :  data.distance, and other data.field .

Answer (score 0):

oh, i can map after snapshotChanges()

```
 const listLoc = this.afdb.list('/userLocations');
listLoc.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    actions.map(action => {
      let data = action.payload.val();
      let placeLocation = {
        lat: data.lat,
        lng: data.lng
      }
      let usersLocation = {
        lat: -7.25747,
        lng: 112.752
      };
       data.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
        usersLocation,
        placeLocation,
        'km'
      ).toFixed(2);
      console.log('the result i expect', data);
    });
  }).subscribe();
```